# Amazon Elastic Beanstalk CLI issues on linux: zlib error

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to use elastic beanstalk cli on an amazon linux instance and I always get zlib module error. This probably is more to do with my linux/unix ignorance but please send any inputs you have.

$ eb init

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.4.0/eb/linux/python3/eb", line                                                                              17, in <module>
    from scli import core
  File "/home/ec2-user/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.4.0/eb/linux/python3/scli/core                                                                             .py", line 24, in <module>
    from scli import command, cli_parse, config_file, prompt
  File "/home/ec2-user/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.4.0/eb/linux/python3/scli/comm                                                                             and.py", line 18, in <module>
    from scli.operation_queue import OperationQueue
  File "/home/ec2-user/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.4.0/eb/linux/python3/scli/oper                                                                             ation_queue.py", line 19, in <module>
    from scli.operation.base import OperationBase
  File "/home/ec2-user/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.4.0/eb/linux/python3/scli/oper                                                                             ation/base.py", line 21, in <module>
    from lib.elasticbeanstalk import eb_utils
  File "/home/ec2-user/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.4.0/eb/linux/python3/lib/elast                                                                             icbeanstalk/eb_utils.py", line 22, in <module>
    from scli import api_wrapper
  File "/home/ec2-user/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.4.0/eb/linux/python3/scli/api_                                                                             wrapper.py", line 19, in <module>
    from lib.elasticbeanstalk.servicecall import ElasticBeanstalkClient
  File "/home/ec2-user/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.4.0/eb/linux/python3/lib/elast                                                                             icbeanstalk/servicecall.py", line 23, in <module>
    from lib.aws.webservice import AWSQueryClient, AWSSignature
  File "/home/ec2-user/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.4.0/eb/linux/python3/lib/aws/w                                                                             ebservice.py", line 26, in <module>
    from . import requests
  File "/home/ec2-user/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.4.0/eb/linux/python3/lib/aws/r                                                                             equests/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/home/ec2-user/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.4.0/eb/linux/python3/lib/aws/r                                                                             equests/utils.py", line 18, in <module>
    import zlib
ImportError: No module named zlib
```

Comment: This is off-topic for SO and belongs on [sf].

Comment: Please install `zlib` (https://www.zlib.net/) and then reinstall Python.